# SVN update after custom patch

Tags: svn

I have this scenario. I checked out a code for one project from a public official SVN repository. Then I applied a custom patch from another source which changed quite a few files.

Now and then official repository gets updates since active developers are committing code there. In order to keep up to date with them I do SVN update.

My question is, will update break my custom stuff? I mean, if a file which was modified by my custom patch gets new revision in official repository will it get overwritten or just official changes will be merged in my custom patched file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [I]f a file which was modified by my custom patch gets new revision in official repository will it get overwritten or just official changes will be merged in my custom patched file?

The changes will be merged into your copy if possible; update will never delete local modifications that you’ve made.

If the files can’t be merged, a conflict will arise and you’ll be notified.

Comment: Is there a way to force SVN to update custom patched files to latest official revision, even if it means reverting custom changes back?